# How to pass the output from a Web Activity into a Copy activity for storage

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure Data Factory and wonder if you can please help me in acheiving with the following scenario:

1. I want to get data from a REST Endpoint using API. The REST Endpoint is stored in a SQL Database table and therefore I fetch the URL using a Lookup activity
2. Further on, I am storing the URL value in a variable using a "Set Variables" activity
3. Post that I am fetching the data from the Endpoint using REST API in a Web activity.
4. Now , I want to store the output data from the Web activity into a Blob storage. For this, i am using Copy activity , but I am not able to get this working at all. Meaning , I am unable to collect the output from the Web Activity into my Copy activity.

In case any of you have come across this situation then it will be of very good help for me indeed.

[image: Failing in the Copy activity]

Comment: Further to clarify, I am getting the following error:   
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "ErrorCode=InvalidParameter,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The value of the property 'value' is invalid: 'The required property is not specified.\r\nParameter name: value'.,Source=,''Type=System.ArgumentException,Message=The required property is not specified.\r\nParameter name: value,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy data1",
    "details": []
}

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not using correct output from web activity in copy activity. To check what is the output from web activity follow this GIF and pass those values appropriately to copy activity

[image]